# How to copy some specific columns and paste it to another columns?

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, how to use VBA to automatically select and copy 4 columns with header including ("DBL planned start", "FPI planned start", "Cent.", and "Pat.")  to columns from "EZ" to "FA"?

I have tried codes as below, but the first part can work, the second part accrued an error.

```
Sub Search()
' Search for "DBL planned start"
For Each Rng In Range("a1:ei1")
    If Rng = "DBL planned start" Then
        a = Rng.Column
    End If
Next
Columns(a).Copy Destination:=Columns("EL")

' Search for "FPI planned start"
For Each Rng In Range("a1:ei1")
    If Rng = "FPI planned start" Then
        a = Rng.Column
    End If
Next
Columns(a).Copy Destination:=Columns("EL")
End Sub
```

Just want to copy columns with header including "DBL planned start", "FPI planned start", "Cent.", and "Pat." to column between "EZ" and "FA".
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want the copy of the 4 columns to append on to the last because if not, your copy operations will overwrite each other.

Comment: I want to keep all the 4 columns. But I don't know how to avoid the overwrite among the 4 columns, is there any solutions for this? Thanks. :-)

Comment: ok, so you want to copy all 4 columns into another 4 columns side by side starting at column EZ, is my understanding correct? I ask because you have 4 columns you want to copy but columns EZ to FA is only 2 columns.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct! I want to select and copy all 4 columns.